# Nodejs fucntion return before operations finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have a question about my Nodejs program. I have a FindItemFromUrlList function which in a for loop calls another TestUrl. I would like FindItemFromUrlList to return the urls found (so the list foundUrls) once all the urls have been tested. But when the for loop is traversed, and that the urls are tested and found, when I do console.log (foundUrls) I have an empty list while in TestUrl. I can see that the Urls have been found and I presume that the algorithm perforsm the console.log function before the for loop, I tried to do a .then but it doesn't work.

```
function FindItemFromUrlList(KeyworList, UrlList, Color, Excludedurls){
    var completed_requests = 0 ;
    var itemfound = 0;
    foundUrls = [];
    for(urls of UrlList){
        completed_requests++;
        TestUrl(KeyworList, urls, itemfound, completed_requests, foundUrls, UrlList, Color, Excludedurls);
    }
    console.log(foundUrls);
}

function TestUrl(KeyworList, urls, itemfound, completed_requests, foundUrls, UrlList, Color, Excludedurls){
    https.get(urls, function (res) {
        var htmlcode2 = "";
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            htmlcode2 += d;
        })
            .on('end', () => {
                for (keyword of KeyworList) {
                    if (htmlcode2.toString().includes(keyword) && !foundUrls.includes(urls) && (!(Excludedurls && urls.includes(Excludedurls))) ){
                        foundUrls.push(urls);
                    }
                }
                if (completed_requests == UrlList.length) {
                    // All download done, process responses
                    console.log("Done all requests");
                    console.log("nombre d'items trouvés : ",foundUrls.length);
                    console.log("Url trouvées :", foundUrls);
                }
            })})
}
```

Here is the result of my code running :

```
[]
Done all requests
nombre d'items trouvés :  5
Url trouvées : [
  'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/jmqsjoxe5/iuawc8jf5',
  'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/jmqsjoxe5/if60rct4l',
  'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/jmqsjoxe5/dgkjtbima',
  'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/jmqsjoxe5/wwx6gdai0',
  'https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/tops-sweaters/jmqsjoxe5/x2y3lk890'
]
```

Comment: Hello. Can you include your code in your post please. This makes it more accessible for people here to help you with your problem. If you are unsure how to format it correctly, someone here will do that for you after you edit your question 

Comment: [Please don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: make you functions async so it can await responses

Answer (score 1):

Your `https.get(...)` is async and receives a callback, which means, your `console.log(foundUrls)` will execute before the `TestUrl` func is finished and `foundUrls` array populated.

```js
async function FindItemFromUrlList(KeyworList, UrlList, Color, Excludedurls){
    var completed_requests = 0 ;
    var itemfound = 0;
    const promises = []
    foundUrls = [];
    for(urls of UrlList){
        completed_requests++;
        const promises = TestUrl(KeyworList, urls, itemfound, completed_requests, foundUrls, UrlList, Color, Excludedurls);
       promises.push(promise)
    }
    
    await Promise.all(promises) // this will wait for promises to resolve
    console.log(foundUrls);
}

async function TestUrl(KeyworList, urls, itemfound, completed_requests, foundUrls, 
  UrlList, Color, Excludedurls) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    https.get(urls, function (res) {
        var htmlcode2 = "";
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            htmlcode2 += d;
        })
            .on('end', () => {
                for (keyword of KeyworList) {
                    if (htmlcode2.toString().includes(keyword) && !foundUrls.includes(urls) && (!(Excludedurls && urls.includes(Excludedurls))) ){
                        foundUrls.push(urls);
                    }
                }

                resolve() // here you resolve the promise

                if (completed_requests == UrlList.length) {
                    // All download done, process responses
                    console.log("Done all requests");
                    console.log("nombre d'items trouvés : ",foundUrls.length);
                    console.log("Url trouvées :", foundUrls);
                }
            })})
  })
    
}
```

You can use async keyword and Promises to handle this. Using `await Promise.all(...)` will wait for all promises to be completed before moving on.
If you've never used Promises before, i suggest you read next [article](https://javascript.info/promise-basics).

Edit: Added code and explanation

Comment: yes i see but how can i execute this console.log after for loop is finished

Comment: @BarnabeMugnier Hey, i edited my answer.  I added the code that i think will solve your problem.